# How can i get the right position?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a little problem with showing the score in my game. I use the 2D camera and if i move my character the score writeing  remains back. I tried this:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: "+ score, new Vector2(10,12350), Color.Gold);
```

[image: look here to see better what i mean]

Comment: Nice to read some Italian on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you draw your tiles by passing a transformation `Matrix` in the `SpriteBatch.Begin()` parameters.

You are probably also drawing the score within the same `SpriteBatch`, so your easy option is to just add the camera position to the score position, plus a little offset like so:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: "+ score, new Vector2(10, camera.Position + 10), Color.Gold);
```

It would be much easier in the future to just create a new `SpriteBatch` after all of your level drawing, and have it at a fixed position in the window.

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: "+ score, new Vector2(10, 10), Color.Gold);
spriteBatch.End()
```